# How to style inner elements of custom Polymer element using external styles?

Tags: css, dom, polymer, shadow-dom, polymer-2.x

Unable to style an element using Shadow DOM with Polymer 1.x or 2.x. Consider the following custom element in Polymer 2.0:

```
<link rel="import" href="../polymer/polymer.html">

<!--
`semantic-ui-button`


@demo demo/index.html
-->

<dom-module id="polymer-button">
  <template>
    <div class$="button {{size}}">{{label}}</div>
  </template>

  <script>
    class MyElement extends Polymer.Element {
      static get is() {
        return 'polymer-button';
      }
      static get properties() {
        return {
          label: {
            type: String,
            value: 'polymer-element'
          },
          size: { type: String }
        };
      }
    }

    window.customElements.define(MyElement.is, MyElement);
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

in the demo:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=yes">

    <title>polymer-element demo</title>

    <script src="../../webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.js"></script>

    <link rel="import" href="../../iron-demo-helpers/demo-pages-shared-styles.html">
    <link rel="import" href="../../iron-demo-helpers/demo-snippet.html">
    <link rel="import" href="../polymer-element.html">

    <style is="custom-style" include="demo-pages-shared-styles"></style>
    <style>
      body { font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif; }
      .button {
        background: #ccc;
        border-radius: 4px;
        color: #444;
      }
      .button.big {
        font-size: 1rem;
        padding: 6px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="vertical-section-container centered">
      <h3>Basic polymer-element demo</h3>
      <demo-snippet>
        <template>
          <polymer-button label="Demo"></polymer-button>
        </template>
      </demo-snippet>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

The styles defined in the demo for `.button` and `.button.big` are *not* applied to the shadow element; however, in Polymer 1.x the styles are applied **if** we use ShadyDOM:

```
<link rel="import" href="../polymer/polymer.html">

<!--
`polymer-button`


@demo demo/index.html
-->

<dom-module id="polymer-button">
  <template>
    <div class$="button {{size}}">{{label}}</div>
  </template>

  <script>
    Polymer({

      is: 'polymer-button',

      properties: {
        label: { type: String }
      },

    });
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

is there a way to select/style these inner elements using [external styles](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/getting-started/primers/shadowdom#stylefromoutside)?

Below is a visual representation of what I said above in order of appearance:

1. Polymer 1.x using Shadow DOM
2. Polymer 1.x using ShadyDOM
3. Polymer 2.x

[image: differences]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To enable styling points, [use CSS variables/mixins](https://www.polymer-project.org/2.0/docs/devguide/custom-css-properties).

1. Add a `<style>` tag to your element's template:

   ```
   <dom-module id="polymer-button">
     <template>
       <style>
         .button {
           @apply --my-button-mixin;
         }
         .button.big {
           @apply --my-button-big-mixin;
         }
       </style>
       ...
     </template>
   </dom-module>
   ```
2. Specify the mixin in a container element:

   ```
   <dom-module id="x-foo">
     <template>
       <style>
         polymer-button {
           --my-button-mixin: {
             background: red;
             color: white;
           };
         }
       </style>
       <polymer-button label="Red button"></polymer-button>
     </template>
   </dom-module>
   ```

   ...or in `index.html`:

   ```
   <body>
     <custom-style>
       <style>
         polymer-button {
           --my-button-mixin: {
             background: red;
             color: white;
           };
         }
       </style>
     </custom-style>
     <polymer-button label="Red button"></polymer-button>
   </body>
   ```

[codepen (Polymer 1)](http://codepen.io/tony19/pen/QpgyXM?editors=1000)

[codepen (Polymer 2)](http://codepen.io/tony19/pen/GWEoPp?editors=1000)

Comment: @djthoms It is actually supported on IE/Edge with the webcomponents polyfills. [screenshots](http://imgur.com/a/UKtal)

Answer (score 5):

Alternately, you can add a `<style>` element with an `@import url` rule inside your custom element `<template>` that will import an external stylesheet:

```
<template>
    <style>
         @import url( external.css )
    </style>
    <div class$="button {{size}}">{{label}}</div>
</template>
```

In your CSS stylesheet (example: *external.css*) you can define standard CSS:

```
.button {
    background: #ccc;
    border-radius: 4px;
    color: #444;
}
.button.big {
    font-size: 1rem;
    padding: 6px;
}
```