# External Styling for CustomElements V1 & ShadowDOM

Tags: javascript, html, css, custom-element, html5-template

**Whilst this may seem to be a duplicate question those asked previously have been based around Polymer, not native CustomElements, and this is about the css itself, not penetrating the ShadowDOM or Custom CSS Properties / Variables**

So here we have a simple Custom Element (note: as of writing this only works in newer Chrome versions)

```js
class StyleMe extends HTMLElement {
 constructor () {
  super();
  let shadow = this.attachShadow({ mode: 'closed' });
  shadow.appendChild(document.querySelector('#style-me').content.cloneNode(true));
 }
}
customElements.define('style-me', StyleMe);
```

```css
h1 {
 /* even !important doesn't penetrate */
 color: red !important;
}
```

```html
<h1>I'm a normal heading</h1>
<style-me>I'm heading hidden in style-me's shadow</style-me>
<template id="style-me">
 <style>
  :host {
   background: blue;
   display: block;
  }
  h1 {
   color: yellow;
  }
 </style>
 <h1><slot></slot></h1>
</template>
```

This demonstrates nicely how styles are isolated when using the ShadowDOM.

What would be nice to do is have the contents of the `<style>` inside `<template>` stored in an external file, possibly generated by a pre-processor such as less.

After much searching only to find answers related to Polymer I've draw a blank, any thoughts?

---

I am not looking for custom properties they would allow me to use

```
<style>
    :host {
        background: blue;
        display: block;
    }
    h1 {
        color: var(--something);
    }
</style>
```

And set the color using

```
style-me {
    --something: yellow;
}
```

My question is about moving

```
:host {
    background: blue;
    display: block;
}
h1 {
    color: yellow;
}
```

Out of a `<style>` tag and into a separate file

Comment: Same answer as for polymer, use [css variables](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_variables). They're part of the spec, have shipped in at least 3 browsers. They aren't unique to polymer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to style inner elements of custom Polymer element using external styles?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42756301/how-to-style-inner-elements-of-custom-polymer-element-using-external-styles)

Comment: CSS Properties really aren't what I'm going for and as mentioned I'm not using Polymer

Comment: CSS variables are not part of custom elements spec.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the CSS `@import url` directive.

```
<template id="style-me">
    <style>
        @import url( '/css/style.css' )
    </script>
    <h1><slot></slot></h1>
</template>
```

The question was [discussed here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40984891/4600982).

Comment: Thank you, that's what I was looking for

Answer (score 1):

I realize this question is more than a year old now, but you might start looking at the [constructible style sheet specification/proposal](https://github.com/WICG/construct-stylesheets/).

That would allow you to do something like:

```js
const customStyleSheet = new CSSStyleSheet();
await customStyleSheet.replace("@import url('/css/style.css')");
shadowDOMReference.adoptedStyleSheets = [ customStyleSheet ];
```