# webcomponents - how to apply external css class to webcomponent

Tags: css, polymer, web-component

I am using `webcomponents-lite (Polymer)` to create webcomponents.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Login</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/util.js"></script>
</head>
<body class="dark">
    <main>
        <edsp-login-form></edsp-login-form>
    </main>
</body>
</html>
```

`<edsp-login-form>` is defined in js file where it uses `lit-html`. The definition as follows:

```
@Define('edsp-login-form', {
  style: ``
})

export class Login extends LitComponent {
render() {
    return html`
    <link rel="import" type="css" href="styles.css">`
    <div></div>
  }
}
```

In this code, **how do apply css classes from `styles.css` to a component `<edsp-login-form>` ?**

Comment: import  style.css inside edsp-login.html <link rel="import" type="css" href="style.css">, it works for now but it will be deprecated soon

Comment: @NagaSaiA tried but not working

Comment: Maybe you could be interested by this post:https://stackoverflow.com/a/42764465/4600982

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1:** If you're using Shadow DOM, you can't apply external CSS to your component. A solution is to deactivate the Shadow DOM by implementing this in your component:

```
createRenderRoot() {
  return this;
}
```

**Option 2:** If you still want to apply external CSS and use Shadow DOM, you can use CSS variables. In your external CSS you can instance the variable using something like:

```
name-of-your-component-tag {
  --variable-name-color: #FFF;
}
```

and then in your component, you can use the CSS variable:

```
.my-class {
  color: var(--variable-name-color);
}
```

**Option 3:** And if you're trying to apply a dark theme, you can use the CSS inside of your component considering the context. In your component you can use CSS like:

```
:host-context(.dark) .bg {
  background: #000;
}
```

Comment: You could apply external CSS to your shadow DOM if you import the CSS into your custom element's js / ts, then within your shadow dom create and append a new style element and add your imported css to the innerHtml of the new style element.